# Don't open Debug panel by default

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a configuration setting that prevents the `Debug` panels (`Variables`, `Watch`, `Call Stack`) and `Debug Console` from opening on debug start / <kbd>F5</kbd>?

Specifically when debugging a node app, its not needed. On a small screen it takes up valuable space and is unneeded.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It is now possible using the **debug.openDebug** User Setting.

You can set it to either:

- neverOpen
- openOnDebugBreak

Comment: This setting seems broken, `openOnDebugBreak` was the default, but unless I misunderstand something my code does not have breaks in it, it was just opening on `start`
Also, changing this changed how the debugger worked. It made me choose from a list of debuggers, and the debuggers were my chrome based browsers. And then it was somehow skipping the panic cases in my code.

TLDR: It looks like this does not simply not open the window, but it turns off the entire debugger and forces you to use a different one that runs your code fundamentally differently.

Answer (score 13):

If you set `"internalConsoleOptions":"neverOpen"` in `.vscode/launch.json`, the Debug Console does not open up when you start debugging.

[Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11372)

Terminology: The Debug Console is officially called `Debug Console Panel`, whereas the view opening on the left side is refered to as `Debug Side Bar`
[All about debugging in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

Comment: Now it changed to `"debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"`

Answer (score 2):

Just open `.vscode/launch.json` in your workspace and set `"externalConsole": true` to not use the VS Code built in console but the OS default one.

Comment: That didn't seem to do what I was looking for, and a bit unclear what the 'OS console' is. I updated the description a bit more to provide more detail.