# How to prevent Run/Debug window to show whenever I start debugging in VSCode

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

Whenever I start debugging my node.js project that run/debug window auto expands. Then I manually have to hide it (ctrl/cmd+B). This interrupts my flow whenever I start debugging. How to keep it hidden until I manually summon it by ctrl/cmd+B.

Here's the screenshot of that 'Run' or 'Debug' Window.

[image]

Here's the launch.json if it helps:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "program": "${file}",
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"]
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach",
      "port": 9229,
      "restart": true,
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "stopOnEntry": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966733/dont-open-debug-panel-by-default

Answer (score 4):

You can prevent the opening of the debug window by adjusting the debug settings.

- Open settings in vscode (ctrl+,)
- Search for debug.openDebug in the search bar
- Select never open in the drop down menu.

Comment: Fixed, Thanks m8